# How to customize the filename of .zip, when build an Eclipse RCP application with Tycho?

Tags: eclipse, tycho

I have an Eclipse RCP application with a product configuration file **com.aa.bb.product**. The `uid` of this .product is `com.aa.bb.product`. When I build it with **Tycho**, the result is **com.aa.bb.product-win32.win32.x86_64.zip**.

This filename is too long, what should I configure to specify the filename like "MyProduct.zip"? Or "MyProduct-win32.win32.x86_64.zip", it's acceptable to keep the **-win32.win32.x86_64** suffix.

Comment: If you ever plan to build for macOS or Linux as well as Windows you need to keep the -win32.win32.x86_64 suffix to distinguish the builds. I think the first part comes from the `uid` in the xxx.product file. I think the tycho configuration would be part of the [tycho-p2-director:archive-products](https://tycho.eclipseprojects.io/doc/3.0.0/tycho-p2/tycho-p2-director-plugin/archive-products-mojo.html) but I don't see anything useful there.

Comment: You can do the renaming e.g. via the maven-antrun-plugin after the ZIP file has been created, see e.g. [here](https://github.com/howlger/IDEalized/blob/06a26209e61801ec9d8133e3e4dbadf24c49bf4b/product/pom.xml#L73-L88).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the pom of the "product" eclipse project:

```
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
        <artifactId>tycho-p2-director-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${tycho-version}</version>

        <configuration>
           <formats>
              <win32>zip</win32>
              <linux>tar.gz</linux>
              <macosx>tar.gz</macosx>
           </formats>

           <products>
              <product>
                 <id>xxxxxx</id>
                 <archiveFileName>xxxxxx</archiveFileName>  <---- the name of the archive
                 <rootFolder>xxxxx</rootFolder>
              </product>
           </products>

        </configuration>
{...}
```

As an example, you can check the`pom.xml` of the"product" project for [JMSToolBox](https://github.com/jmstoolbox/jmstoolbox):
https://github.com/jmstoolbox/jmstoolbox/blob/dev/org.titou10.jtb.product/pom.xml

(I'm the author of JMSToolBox)